# Regex pattern to match Dutch mobile phone numbers

Tags: python, regex

I have written 4 regex statements to extract different ways of writing a Dutch mobile number:

```
* regex 1: r'(\s06[0-9]{8}\s)              --> 0611111111
* regex 2: r'(\s06-[0-9]{8}\s)'            --> 06-1111111
* regex 3: r'(\s06\s[0-9]{8}\s)'           --> 06 1111111
* regex 4: r'(\s06\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{4}\s)' --> 06 1111 111
```

I have tried combining these into a single regex.

```
* combi regex 1: r'(06[-\s]?[0-9]{8}\s)' <-- matched 1,2,3
* combi regex 2: r'(\s06[-\s]?[0-9]{4,9}[-\s]?[0-9]{4,9}\s)' <-- matched 1,2,3,4
```

Unfortunately this `combi regex 2`, which should match all types of numbers does not quite work.
This regex for example also matches: `061111111111` and this number is too long to be a phone number.

I know it has to do with the `{4,9}` statement in my regex. How can I alter my regex so that it will match all 4 numbers?

Comment: Try `(?<!\S)06(?:[0-9]{8}|[ -][0-9]{7}| [0-9]{4} [0-9]{3})(?!\S)` - https://regex101.com/r/hN5pdc/1

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't do what I need it to do. It only seems to match with regex 1 (0611111111)

Comment: Again, see https://regex101.com/r/hN5pdc/1 - all four are matched. Show your exact test case in the question body.

Comment: I think it might be because I'm extracting phone numbers from a large number of text files. All I can see is that my combi regex 2 matches more numbers (all be it a few erroneous once) than this regex from 101.  Thanks for your help either way.

Comment: Show the real text, the way you get it in the code, and the way you are using the regex.

Answer (score -1):

try this one might work.

```
(\s06[-\s]?(?:[0-9]{8}|[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{4})\s)
```